# MySQL query: list of tag.names and lang which isn't already inserted in combination inside images_urls

Tags: database, mysql

I can't figure out any good way to get a list of tag.names and lang which isn't already inserted in combination inside images_urls.

My database looks something like this.

```
tags

  name    user_id
+-------+---------+
|hi     |    1    | 
|friend |    1    |
|friend |    2    |
|people |    2    |
+-------+---------+

users

 id   lang
+---+------+
| 1 |  en  |
| 2 |  sv  |
+---+------+

images_urls

  name     lang
+--------+------+
| hi     |  en  |
| friend |  sv  |
+--------+------+
```

What I would like to have returned would be:

```
result

 name     lang
+-------+------+
|friend |  en  |
|people |  sv  |
+-------+------+
```

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT tags.name, users.lang
FROM tags, users
WHERE tags.user_id = users.id
AND CONCAT(tags.name, ',', users.lang) NOT IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(name, ',', lang) FROM images_urls
)
GROUP BY CONCAT(name, ',', lang)
ORDER BY SUM(tags.count) DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why `images_urls` has a name instead of a `user_id`, but this should work:

```
SELECT t.name, u.lang
FROM tags t
JOIN users u ON ( u.id = t.user_id )
LEFT JOIN images_urls iu ON ( iu.name=t.name AND iu.lang=u.lang )
WHERE iu.name IS NULL
```

Using the `LEFT JOIN` returns `NULL` for rows that do not exist in `images_urls`, so I check for that.

Comment: This seems to work.
images_urls has name because the image represents a tag and not a user.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tags.name, users.lang
FROM tags, users
WHERE tags.user_id = users.id
AND users.name NOT IN (SELECT name from images_urls);
```

I would suggest images_urls should contain user_id not name, but thats a different issue.

column NOT IN ('name`','name1','name2','name3')

is also valid for testing purposes.

Comment: I doubt that this will return the correct results. In the example it would not return `friend  en`, as there is an `image_url` with `friend` (but not the right one).